# AutoIt - Crash without #RequireAdmin for opening a url

Tags: internet-explorer, admin, autoit

If I run in test.au3 :

```
#requireadmin
#include<IE.au3>

$oIE = _IECreate("www.google.com", 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

It successfully opens a new Internet Explorer window and navigates to www.google.com.

Now if I remove #requireadmin and run:

```
#include<IE.au3>

$oIE = _IECreate("www.google.com", 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

It just opens the window and doesn't navigate to the URL. Around 15 seconds later it crashes with:

```
---------------------------
AutoIt Error
---------------------------
Line 272  (File "\\intra.saaq.net\sb\du\du02\gar25\Desktop\outil_outlook\sources\Include\IE.au3"):

$oObject.navigate($sUrl)
$oObject^ ERROR

Error: The requested action with this object has failed.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Why is #requireadmin required to simply navigate to a URL?
Is there any way around it?

Using AutoIt3.exe - 3.3.14.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a Windows security issue.

[The AutoIt help for `_IECreate()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IECreate.htm) describes a few work-arounds; the `#RequireAdmin` being one of them...

> New security in Windows Vista causes a new browser window to be
>   created when a browser is instructed to navigate to a URL in a
>   different security zone.
>
> This occurs as well with the initial creation and navigation initiated
>   with _IECreate().
>
> The new window is a new browser instance and the previous browser
>   object variable no longer points to it.
>
> There are several workarounds:
>
> 1) add #RequireAdmin to your code (this is required even if the
>   account is part of the Administrator's Group and will prompt for
>   credentials if necessary),
>
> 2) use _IEAttach() to connect to the new browser window
>
> 3) add the target website to the Trusted Sites security zone in IE,
>
> 4) turn off "Protected Mode" in IE,
>
> or 5) disable UAC. Care must be taken to understand the implications
>   of disabling IE security features when accessing untrusted sites.

Comment: If it can help anyone i ended up using a simpler method which works without requireadmin:

run( "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE -new http:// url.com")

Winwait ("title xyz")